# Xcode Project Files not appearing in Project Navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Strange problem here...my project's Swift files, Main.Storyboard, additional images, delegate, etc. files are all missing from Xcodes Project Navigator.

What is really strange is that the project builds fine and I can also select them from the top of the main editor window even though they are not displayed on the left in the Project Navigator.

When I open my project, the files appear for about 1/2 a second, and then the list is condensed to the blue target file at the top and about 7 images. (I cannot post a picture because my reputation is not high enough.)

I've quit and reopened Xcode and also performed a few restarts, but I still can't select them...even though they're apparently there! Any ideas?

Comment: Tried clicking on the blue target file yet?

Comment: Yep sure have...Its only drilling down to show a few image files.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

May be you need check the Project Navigator's bottom, there is a search bar.

If the search bar had some keywords, the Project Navigator would only show the files which file's name contain the keyword(s), and you can't clear the keyword by only reopen Xcode.

When you open Xcode, Xcode will initial the search bar with nothing and you can see the complete files, after initial had done, Xcode will load last close time's state for the search bar and filter files, so that's why `When I open my project, the files appear for about 1/2 a second`.

Comment: That was totally it! I've never used that search bar before, so I don't really know how it got filled. Thanks beimenjun

Comment: This answer should be protected to prevent exactly what I'm about to say: thanks!

Comment: I know this is against the rules but thanks for saving the day!

Comment: I am a little bit late, but this answer just saved my life. Thanks man

Answer (score 79):

For me the issue was different.  My search bar was empty but I had mistakenly selected the clock icon in the search bar at the bottom of the navigator.

**Unselected it looks like this**

[image]

**Selected it look like this**

[image]

The clock icon filters the files for files that have been recently used and therefore, hides a number of your files.

Comment: Woah, I would've never guessed. This was my case as well

Comment: Brilliant! Saved me a lot of time ;-)

Comment: Worked for me !! Woahh.

Comment: This was my issue too. Thank you!

Comment: Jesus Christ, I've been using Xcode for 5 years, never noticed this before!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Untick this timer icon at the bottom of navigator in case you have selected it

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing a copy of the file that was being referenced by the code module where the error was occurring but was not being referenced by the project file in Project Navigator.  Explanation:  I had long ago moved a file to a different directory and changed the reference in the project, but had not deleted the original version of the file.  The file still existed on the file system in the original location  but was being referenced by the project file and Project Navigator (.xcodeproj) in a new location.  The referencing code module still found the file in then old location and did not update the pointer to the new location automatically.  Simply deleting the file in the old location fixed this issue for me.

I debugged this by drilling into the referenced file by right clicking on the object name in code which opened up the module in a code window and then right clicking on the code and selecting "Show in finder".  I then compared this location to the location found in the Project Navigator by right clicking on the file name there and selecting "Show in Finder".

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had added the project file instead of the project folder in Xcode. I recommend closing the window, opening another instance of Xcode with the FOLDER that contains the project in it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What would you have changed about what I wrote to improve it. That link, doesn't give specifics.

@Trenton_M

Comment: Part of the issue is the question is 4 years old, with an accepted answer.  What you have provided doesn’t really add much to that; it should really just be included as a comment.  At least in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by the clock icon as mentioned by @jonthornham. For a detailed explanation, please visit this site: https://xalting.com/2019/12/26/what-to-do-if-your-files-are-not-showing-up-in-xcode/.

Answer (score -2):

This is caused by conflicts project.pbxproj file inside your projects, to get out of this error just follow bellow steps.

1. Find the backup of your project, if you don't have any backup copy "project.pbxproj" file from another (any) project. its located inside "projectName.xcodeproj" just copy it by clicking show package contents.
2. Replace this file in your current project.

Thats it!

Happy Coding