# Project Not Opening in XCode

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods, pull

My partner and I are using git to share our Xcode project. We accidentally added the same cocoapod and when I pulled from GitHub my project now won't open.

The merge error is in the `podfile.lock` but I can't figure out how to access that to fix it.
I've tried everything I can find on the internet which led me to the `podfile.lock` but I can't figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Do you see an error message similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/21366549/6309?

Comment: @VonC the error says project cannot load

Comment: OK. Could you edit your question with more details (OS, version of XCode, and Git, exact error message, screenshots, ...)

Comment: I found that the only solution to this problem that I could find was deleting the project and redownloading from github

Comment: Follow my answer on bellow link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377721/3472881

Comment: Follow my answer on bellow link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377721/3472881

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the error message is about

```
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock
Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation
```

The usual workaround is to delete to Pod from the project, but here, the goal is to keep it, so, as the [OP Ethan Hardacre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7437210/ethan-hardacre) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095055/project-not-opening-in-xcode/45137246#comment77237911_45095055):

> the only solution to this problem that I could find was deleting the project and redownloading from GitHub.

In other words, keep the one that was pushed first to GitHub.